# wxPython - Ampersand as shortcut key in menu

Tags: python, user-interface, wxpython, shortcut, ampersand

this might be a bit of an edge case, but I'm hoping it's still possible.. I want to set the '&' key as a shortcut for one of my menus. Currently, the code looks like given below, which correctly displays the ampersand, but does not set it as shortcut key. Furthermore, replacing it with the string `"'&&&' as Separator"` will highlight the single quote as the shortcut key for this menu item. Is this doable at all?

`...
settingsAmpersand = settingsmenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "'&&' as Separator",   " Set the separator to ampersand", wx.ITEM_RADIO);
...`

Answer (score 0):

from the docs

> ... An accelerator key can be specified using the ampersand &
>   character. In order to embed an ampersand character in the menu item
>   text, the ampersand must be doubled.
>
> Optionally you can specify also an accelerator string appending a tab
>   character \t followed by a valid key combination (e.g. CTRL+V ). Its
>   general syntax is any combination of "CTRL" , "RAWCTRL" , "ALT" and
>   "SHIFT" strings (case doesn’t matter) separated by either '-' or '+'
>   characters and followed by the accelerator itself. Notice that CTRL
>   corresponds to the “Ctrl” key on most platforms but not under Mac OS
>   where it is mapped to “Cmd” key on Mac keyboard. Usually this is
>   exactly what you want in portable code but if you really need to use
>   the (rarely used for this purpose) “Ctrl” key even under Mac, you may
>   use RAWCTRL to prevent this mapping. Under the other platforms RAWCTRL
>   is the same as plain CTRL .

so maybe

```
settingsmenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, "'&&' as Separator\tCTRL+&",   " Set the separator to ampersand"...
```

might work... maybe... I cant really test it atm (you should have provided a complete working example)

Comment: Tried it, but it doesn't seem to work. Also, I do not want to add any accelerator string, just simply highlight the ampersand, which the paragraph you quoted does not into further. Thanks for the try, and the reason I did not provide a complete working example is that I felt that this was not necessary as I had hoped this specific edge case would have been encountered by someone else already (and thus would hopefully be easily resolvable).